# Get Application State key name by index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding several values to application state like:

```
for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count;i++)
    Application[MyList[i].Id.ToString()] = MyList[i].Value;
```

Then I want to remove the values for Ids that are expired (not in the current my list). So I want to loop through all Application state values and remove them If Id has expired. something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<Application.Count;i++)
{
    int Id = int.Parse(Application[i].Key);  // Here is what I want to do but I don't have access to key value
    if(!MyList.Any(l => l.Id == Id) Application[Id.ToString()] = null;
}
```

I have thought of a way like adding the Id to its value like:

```
for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count;i++)
    Application[MyList[i].Id.ToString()] = MyList[i].Id.ToString() + "," + MyList[i].Value;
```

And then:

```
   for(int i=0;i<Application.Count;i++)
{
    int Id = int.Parse(Application[i].Split(',')[0]);  
    if(!MyList.Any(l => l.Id == Id) Application[Id.ToString()] = null;
}
```

But doesn't seem the correct way to do it. I think there must be a way to get the key, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`AllKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.allkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

```
foreach (string key in Application.AllKeys)
{
    int id;
    if (Int32.TryParse(key, out id))
    {
        if (!MyList.Any(l => l.Id == id))
        {
            Application.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot. why didn't I thought of AllKeys. its awkward